# Is using MYSQL with EF got any better?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to use MYSQL with Entityframework and banging my head even for minor isssues.

I still haven't figured out what are all the missing pieces?have issues generating views? running into below error while generating views...want to know if it is something purse on or drop it?I see MSSQL is the preferred option with ASP.net web API,want to get an opinion if there will be any technical issues one can encounter using ASP.net and MySQL

App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework codeConfigurationType="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6">
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <!--defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"-->
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6"></provider>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"></provider></providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="QlasrServiceEntitiesConnection" connectionString="metadata=res://*/QlasrServiceModel.csdl|res://*/QlasrServiceModel.ssdl|res://*/QlasrServiceModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=cte-sql-dev4;initial catalog=QCA_DEV;persist security info=True;user id=ListenerAppUser;password=L@pp7x7x;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="QlasrServiceConnectionEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/QlasrServiceModel.csdl|res://*/QlasrServiceModel.ssdl|res://*/QlasrServiceModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=cte-sql-dev4;initial catalog=QCA_DEV;persist security info=True;user id=ListenerAppUser;password=L@pp7x7x;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="BitDatabaseEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/BitDatabaseModel.csdl|res://*/BitDatabaseModel.ssdl|res://*/BitDatabaseModel.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=10.52.244.189;user id=wciadmin;password=adSHEEP91min;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=aci_dev&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data" publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.8.8.0" newVersion="6.8.8.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data></configuration>
```

Error:-

```
error 0152: No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient'. Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection.Loader.ThrowOnNonWarningErrors()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection.Loader.LoadItems(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 sourceFilePaths)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection.Loader..ctor(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 sourceFilePaths, Boolean throwOnError, IDbDependencyResolver resolver)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection.Init(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 filePaths, Boolean throwOnError, IDbDependencyResolver resolver, DbProviderManifest& providerManifest, DbProviderFactory& providerFactory, String& providerInvariantName, String& providerManifestToken, Memoizer`2& cachedCTypeFunction)
```

Comment: Show me your connection string. Also, make sure you have added reference of entityframework.

Comment: Install the [MySQL Provider here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html) on the machine you're running this application (maybe your machine or some IIS server) and try again.

Comment: @Justcode - Updated my questions with my App.config,is that what you want?yes,I do have reference to EF,infact I can get everything to work apart from generating views,please provide guidance

Comment: @Alisson - I already have that link ,I've using the same link so far..as mentioned in above comment I can get everything to work apart from generating views

Comment: What do you mean by "generating views"? You mean **SQL Views**?

Comment: @Alisson  - I mean https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469601(v=vs.113).aspx